# openssl pass first few lines from script then read from stdin

Tags: bash, shell, openssl

I want to run `openssl` and have it begin with the following commands sent to the server:

```
t authenticate <dynamically generated base64 string from calling script>
t select Inbox
```

Then from there take input from `stdin`.  I'm very ignorant in shell scripting and the openssl toolkit, and I certainly don't see how to do this simply with piping / redirecting `stdin` unless perhaps I tried setting up a file that was simultaneously drawing from `stdin` itself, or such.

I'm not exactly sure the technologies openssl uses to read its input.  For example the following:

```
$ echo "t login testacct@yahoo.com password" | openssl s_client -connect imap.mail.yahoo.com:993
```

Does not do the same thing as

```
openssl s_client -connect imap.mail.yahoo.com:993
# openssl dialogue opens...
C: t login testacct@yahoo.com password
S: t NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Incorrect username or password. (#YSH002)
```

I imagine `openssl` is opening a new shell session (I'm weak in my understanding here) and it does not pass its arguments from `stdin` to the inner shell it creates.

Comment: You don't "log into openssl" -- it seems you want to speak either POP or IMAP after authentication? Or is this some home-grown protocol?

Comment: @ShiDoiSi - you're right, just run openssl however the first command I will send is IMAP's authenticate.  So I was just thinking of it as logging in.

Comment: @djechlin: Can't your script write to a file, then you use `tee -a` to redirect stdin (and append) to that same file? This would allow you to read everything from a single input: the file.

Comment: @djechlin: ahh, I think I understand your problem now. Do you want to redirect your commands to a process' stdin (respecting the newlines)? Try `echo -e "t login testacct@yahoo.com password\n" | openssl s_client -connect imap.mail.yahoo.com:993`. You can also redirect the contents of a file, which I think is what you'll have to do next, if this works as you expect. (footnote: I have to go, but I'll be back later)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend splitting the problem into two scripts:

Firstly you have one script that echoes the initial commands that you want to send and then reads from stdin and writes to stdout. Like this (call it script1.sh for instance):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "first command"
echo "second command"
while read x
do
  echo "$x"
done
```

The second script then just bundles the arguments to openssl so you don't have to keep typing them (call this script2.sh for instance. Note that as with script1.sh above, you should have the #!/bin/bash on the first line to tell the OS that it's a bash script.

then you can just type:

```
script1.sh | script2.sh
```

and you'll get the first two lines passed to openssl and then everything you type will get passed after that. If you want to always finish with a few commands you can add them after the while loop in script1.sh.

You terminate the whole thing with Ctrl-D

If openssl echoes the input you type then you will get the lines you type in shown twice (which is a bit irritating). In that case the "-s" argument to "read" will suppress the first line (useful for typing passwords for instance)

Note that this solution is similar to the solution suggested earlier with the temporary file and the tail -f but it avoids the need for a temporary file and everything is done in a single line.

The problem with the solution given in the question is that stdin to the openssl command is closed when the 'echo "t login ..."' command finishes and this will generally cause programs to exit. With the solution given here the pipe connects the stdout of the first script to the stdin of the second and everything typed into read will get passed on to openssl

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I needed.  Question though - why did this work but when I feed into `script2.sh` via a `tail -f tempfile`, everything I typed into the window with `openssl` running didn't work, as in, it was printed to the screen but the server didn't do anything with it, as if it were not actually sent?

Comment: could you explain a bit more what you did. Basically you need some program to read input from the keyboard and pass it through a pipe to the openssl command. The terminal will echo your typing to the screen even if there is nothing else reading it. So "tail -f tempfile" and then typing at the screen will not get anything into the tempfile to be passed on to openssl

Answer (score 2):

None of these solutions return control of stdin to the user. This should pass first command and second command to openssl and then read stdin:

```
cat <<EOF - | openssl ....
first command
second command
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic SSL/TLS connection to an SSL-enabled IMAP server can be established through `s_client`:

```
openssl s_client -connect imapserver.example.com:143 -starttls imap
```

Note the trailing `-starttls imap`: openssl "knows" how to tell the IMAP server that it would like to move from the plain-text connection (as you would get with telnet) to the SSL-secured.

After this, openssl's job is done, and you need to speak proper IMAP to the server, *including authentification*!

Comment: Yes that part I all know.  I'm asking how the first few lines can to be entered can come from a script and the rest I can type in myself.  This is for testing purposes where I don't enjoy typing out the authenticate command and select inbox each time, which I always do when testing, even though what I do after that is a free-for-all.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your script to write the commands to a file, and then use `tee -a` to redirect `stdin` to that same file. Let me show you an example:

```
jweyrich@pharao:~$ echo "command1" > cmds
jweyrich@pharao:~$ tee -a cmds > /dev/null
command2
command3
^C
```

In the mean time, I was running `tail -f cmds` in another tty:

```
jweyrich@pharao:~$ tail -f cmds 
command1
command2
command3
```

This will turn that file into the single source you have to read and process.

Comment: Okay, this is definitely a step in the right direction, but ideally I'd like to get this down to a single screen so I'm not looking at input dialogue and left and output dialogue on right.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that you can use Nick's solution as one-line script:

```
$ sh -c 'echo "first command"; echo "second command"; while read x; do  echo "$x"; done' | whatever
```