# OpenSSL Script to run checks in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, openssl

I have the following command.

```
openssl s_client -connect my.site.com:443
```

This connects, so then I type the following:

```
GET /ws/map/v1/search.wsdl HTTP/1.1
Host: my.site.com
```

This returns the xml I'm looking for from the wsdl.

However, I'm finding it hard to script it to run as one job.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'openssl s_client -connect my.site.com:443'
echo 'GET /ws/map/v1/search.wsdl HTTP/1.1
Host: my.site.com'
while read x
do
  echo "$x"
done
```

Is there something i'm missing here when trying to send this command to the ssl console, and have it read to a var that I can work with??

Thanks much!
Ben

okay, so now I have script 1 which has the following.

```
#!/bin/bash
openssl s_client -connect my.site.com:443
```

and script 2 does

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'GET /ws/map/v1/search.wsdl HTTP/1.1'
echo 'Host: my.site.com'
while read x
do
  echo "$x"
done
```

and when I type 
    script1.sh | script2.sh

and I get : bad interpreter: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.

any ideas?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707092/openssl-pass-first-few-lines-from-script-then-read-from-stdin

Comment: thanks devnull, can you take a look above again? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it!
 :)

```
echo -e "GET /ws/map/v1/search.wsdl HTTP/1.1\nHost: my.site.com\n\n" | openssl s_client -connect my.site.com:443 -ign_eof
```

Really hope this helps someone going forward.