# run commands into openssl through batch

Tags: powershell, batch-file, openssl

i am trying to set up a custom script in uptime monitoring and have this command run openssl and have arguments that i pass into it run.

```
openssl s_client -CAfile C:\apcerts\certs\ -quiet -connect ${HOST}:${PORT} > ${TMPF} 2>&1 < EOF
<TF80DOC><XPLN/></TF80DOC>
EOF

if (Select-String "Update Level" ${TMPF} > /dev/null)
{
    exitstatus=$STATE_OK
    Select-String "Update Level" ${TMPF} | sort | uniq}
elseif (Select-String "Regulatory" ${TMPF} > /dev/null)
{
    exitstatus=$STATE_OK
    Select-String "Regulatory" ${TMPF} | sort | uniq}
else{
    echo `date` >> /tmp/caught_errs.out
    cat ${TMPF} >> /tmp/caught_errs.out
    echo " "    >> /tmp/caught_errs.out
    exitstatus=$STATE_CRITICAL
    }
rm -f ${TMPF} 2> /dev/null

exit ${exitstatus}
```

i want to have the variables ${host}:${port} are left blank and i want to have an argument that i manually put information in and the fields populate with that information.

for example i need to connect to blank-xml.myinfo.com:30011.

the problem i am running into is when i set this up on the custom monitors i have a .bat that opens openssl but cannot open the .txt file to run commands given.

what do i need to do in order for this to work.

### Update:

I have made a batch file that passes in information to openssl that is a lot smaller.

```
@echo off
c:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl s_client -connect help-xml.helpme.com:443
```

this section works great shows information on the screen that is needed. I need to send in another command to the window also but get a error stating the the < command isn't an executable or batch process.

that command is `<TF80DOC><XPLN/></TF80DOC>` i have tried using the & symbol and have used echo before it but still am getting the same error or the screen will pop up and close instantly with no information.

the if then statement works after i run `<TF80DOC><XPLN/></TF80DOC>` since this has information that is displayed the statement is looking for. But if i can't get the `<TF80DOC><XPLN/></TF80DOC>` to be sent to openssl after the `s_client -connect help-xml.helpme.com:443` runs then the if statement will never work.

### Update:

I have changed the powershell command to pipe in the command after `s_client -connect help-xml.helpme.com:443`

the new code looks like

```
@' 
<TF90DOC><XPLN/></TF90DOC>
'@ | C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl s_client -quiet -connects_client -connect help-xml.helpme.com:443 > test1.txt 2>&1
```

the if then statement isn't an issue since i know how to fix that part of it. the powershell part of the code works but requires me to press enter which is not what i need it to do. i need it to execute the command automatically without user input

For the batch command i have made some slight changes to it, which are

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
set "var=<TF90DOC><XPLN/></TF90DOC>"

echo echo !var! | C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl s_client -connect tf90-xml.bsi.com:443> test1.txt 2>&1
```

this command still gives me the error

> < was unexpected at this time.

Comment: how would i write `<TF80DOC><XPLN/></TF80DOC>` as a variable.

Comment: okay i will have to try that. i will let you know what happens

Comment: i have the same problem as i did before. which is < was unexpected at this time

Comment: What language is that script at the top?  Is that PowerShell?  bash?  If it's Powershell, try escaping the `<` and `>` with a backtick (with a `\`` character, usually located above [Tab]).  So `$xml = "<TF80DOC><XPLN/></TF80DOC>"` doesn't work, try `\`<TF80DOC\`>\`<XPLN/\`>\`</TF80DOC\`>`.  [More info on escaping in PowerShell](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html).  If you aren't using PowerShell, ignore all that.  This is confusing.  `Select-String` looks like a PowerShell cmdlet, but `/dev/null` is a Linux thing.

Comment: the top part is Powershell. i have figured out a way for that top part to see the command and input it into at the end of the file. But i need  it to press enter automatically or force the command to run in order for the function to be actually ran. i have to press enter manually which isn't what i need to do.

Comment: It seems you've made several changes to your code based on comments - could you post the latest code so we can see how it's currently [not] working?

Comment: sure i will edit the post and add the new information for the batch and powershell

Answer (score 1):

I completely misunderstood your question at first and didn't realize you needed to send the command to the newly-opened openssl instance. In order to do this, you need to pipe the command you want to openssl.

```
@echo off
echo ^<TF80DOC^>^<XPLN/^>^</TF80DOC^>|c:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl s_client -connect help-xml.helpme.com:443
```

Note that this is untested, and you may have to also escape the escape characters:

```
echo ^^^<TF80DOC^^^>^^^<XPLN/^^^>^^^</TF80DOC^^^>|c:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl s_client -connect help-xml.helpme.com:443
```

If you need to send more than one command, place them in a separate batch file with each command preceded by an `echo` and pipe that to the openssl command, like this:

**commands.bat**

```
@echo off
echo echo This is one command.
echo echo This is another command.
```

**main.bat**

```
@echo off
commands.bat|C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl s-client -connect help-xml.helpme.com:443
```

Comment: the error that is given is < was unexpected at this time

Comment: @bgrif - Two days later I came across [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13789601/4158862) which seems to be essentially what you're looking for, but in bash. I've edited my answer to better fit your needs.

Comment: the `echo ^^^<TF80DOC^^^>^^^<XPLN/^^^>^^^</TF80DOC^^^>|c:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl s_client -connect help-xml.helpme.com:443` command pauses and waits for the user to press enter. this is closer to what i am trying to do with the batch part of the command. i still need to get no user input for it to run fully.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Try this:</strike> (See edit below.)

```
@echo off
(
    echo(^^^<TF90DOC^^^>^^^<XPLN/^^^>^^^</TF90DOC^^^>
    echo;
) | C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl s_client -connect tf90-xml.bsi.com:443 > test1.txt 2>&1
```

### Edit:

From what you describe, it sounds like openssl is not ready for input immediately after entry of that XML, and is black holing the newline piped to stdin.  So rather than dumping everything to stdin at once, you'll need to introduce a sleep of some sort, and listen to that program's stdout for the appropriate prompt.

Here's a proof of concept in JScript that I think can be applied for you as soon as I know what text openssl uses to prompt for the XML, and then for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress.  This is a similar method as described on the [WSHScriptExec StdOut Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbxxzwb5%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) documentation page, and is more flexible than any solution attempted thusfar.

**test.bat**

```
@if (@a==@b) @end   /*  begin multiline JScript comment

:: batch portion

@echo off
setlocal

cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0"

goto :EOF
    
:: end batch portion / begin JScript */
var osh = new ActiveXObject('wscript.shell'),
    fso = new ActiveXObject('scripting.filesystemobject'),
    log = fso.CreateTextFile('output.txt', true),
    read;

var exe = osh.Exec('cmd /c test2.bat');

while (1) {
    if (!exe.StdOut.AtEndOfStream) {
        read += exe.StdOut.Read(1); // read 1 char at a time
        if (/Arg 1:/.test(read)) {
            WSH.Sleep(50);
            exe.StdIn.Write('<TF80DOC><XPLN/></TF80DOC>\n');
            WSH.Sleep(100);

            // This is the output we wish to capture.
            read = exe.StdOut.ReadLine();
            WSH.Echo(read);
            log.WriteLine(read);

            read = '';
        } else if (/Press any key/.test(read)) {
            WSH.Sleep(100);
            exe.StdIn.Write('\n');
            break;
        }
    }
    else WSH.Sleep(100);
}
log.Close();

while (!exe.Status) WSH.Sleep(100);
WSH.Echo('Done.');
```

**test2.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /P "input=Arg 1: "

echo(Input: !input!

pause
```

Comment: the test.bat and test2.bat worked like you showed. which is really good. i have tried everything you suggested and still it pauses when i try to to do all the openssl stuff.

Comment: i will keep on trying different ways to get this to work

Comment: @bgrif I had a different idea.  See my edit.  If you need help tailoring it to your situation, let me know the text for the prompt for your XML string, whether you want everything logged or just a specific line, and the text for the "Press Enter" dealio.