# Batch scripting email download through openssl

Tags: windows, email, batch-file, openssl, imap

I am trying to write a batch file that connects to google's mail server and downloads mail through IMAP. Using the response [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298364/run-commands-into-openssl-through-batch) I have the following files:

email.cmd

```
C:\path\to\commands.bat | C:\path\to\openssl.exe s_client -crlf -connect imap.gmail.com:993
cmd /k
```

commands.bat

```
@echo off
echo tag login user@gamil.com password
echo tag SELECT INBOX
echo tag LOGOUT
```

Running the email.bat file on Windows Server 2012 that connects to Google's IMAP server and waits for a return character to run the other commands. This works for logging in, but does not run any of the commands after `tag login ...` and returns the message.

```
tag OK user@gmail.com authenticated (Success)
tag BAD Could not parse command
tag BAD Could not parse command
DONE
```

What is wrong here that is causing openssl to not be able to parse the commands?

Comment: Is there any wait between commands?  Technically, SELECT is not legal until the OK has been transmitted by the server.

Comment: There isn't an explicit wait between commands. I looked through the documentation and Google and didn't see a way to do it. Would it be possible to run the openssl shell in the background and pipe commands to it from a batch file that can include delays?

Comment: batch is really not the language to do this...  IMAP is an interactive protocol, you are not going to get very far by blasting commands at the server.

Comment: I thought that might be the case.

Comment: IMAP clients may legally send lots of commands at the same time, and an IMAP server can benefit from parsing everything it receives as soon as it arrives. Your second and subsequent commands aren't legal yet when you send them. If the server waits with parsing until it has executed the first command to completion, then they'll be legal when the server gets around to parsing. But the server is not required to wait, and if it doesnt you'll get exactly the errors you see.

Answer (score 0):

According to [IMAP4rev1 documentation (RFC 2060)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2060#section-2.2.1):

> The client command begins an operation.  Each client command is
> prefixed with an identifier (typically a short alphanumeric string,
> e.g. `A0001`, `A0002`, etc.) called a "tag".  **A different tag** is generated
> by the client **for each command**.

Thus, your `commands.bat` could be as follows:

```
@echo off
echo tag001 login user@gamil.com password
echo tag002 SELECT INBOX
echo tag333 LOGOUT
```

Comment: A server won't reject identical tags.

Comment: The server is still authenticating from the first tag and then returning the `could not parse command` error for the other commands.